# Managed Package Field API

Tags: managed-package

I have a managed package installed in my dev org. In one of the objects belonging to the managed package say `Object1__c` there is a custom field with the API `'namespaceprefix__abc__c'`. I have added a new custom field with the API `'abc__c'`. Both the fields are look ups to Account and Contact respectively.
I have a before insert trigger on the object `'Object1__c'` which should override `namespaceprefix__abc__c` value based on the `abc__c`. when I debug the `Trigger.New` list, I find that the `abc__c` is holding an Account record's Id instead of Contact record value. Can anyone explain this weird behavior of the field API's ?

Comment: Does the managed package perhaps have a before insert trigger that is doing something you're not aware of?

Comment: It does have one, but how can it affect a custom field outside package?

Comment: The managed package could be discovering your field by making a describe call that returns all the fields. And it might be using a naming convention that ignores the namespace prefix to allow local fields to be added or just work based on the type of the field. I'd first try using a different name for your local field and then contact the author of the managed package and ask them what they are doing if you are sure the problem isn't in your code.

Comment: The managed package author has confirmed of no such manipulation/usage being done inside the package. For now, I have updated the local field's API. But I would, still want to understand why this weird behavior? I have worked previously with the same scenario but never once faced this issue and always thought salesforce treated such fields unique based on their API's

Comment: you've referred to fields 'namespaceprefix__abc__c' and 'abc__c', whilst I appreciate these wont be the correct field names, are the field names the same for the managed vs the non-managed fields?

Comment: 'abc' is just the terminology that I am using here to refer the actual fields in the org. The field names are same except the 'namespaceprefix'.